# PLotting a Gaussian in python

Tags: statistics

so I am trying to plot a histogram of my data and I seem to be a little confused here. I am using matplotlib in python. Here is the code from their website:

```
 mu = 100 #mean
sigma = 15 #std deviation
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

I am confused as to what the x -axis should be for my use. I have calculated the standard deviation and the mean but, I am uncertain if I should replace the np.random.randn(10000) with the actual data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy method `np.random.randn` returns a number of random numbers with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. So `np.random.randn(10000)` returns 10000 random numbers that are normally distributed around $0$.

By multiplying by `sigma`, you make the resulting distribution normally distributed around $0$ with standard deviation `sigma`. By adding `mu`, you shift the distribution to become the one you want, with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

In this programming snippet, they use the array `x` for plotting purposes - they literally plot $10000$ points that were randomly generated in that fashion.